# React / Redux app dispatching an action inside settimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to dispatch an action inside settimeout, but getting error. I am having this code inside a container

Code

```
setTimeout(function(){ this.props.getData(); }, 3000);
```

Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined
```

However `this.props.getData();` works fine outside of settimeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to bind `this` to the callback of `setTimeout`.

Like this: `setTimeout(function(){ this.props.getData(); }.bind(this), 3000);`

OR

`setTimeout(()=>{this.props.getData();},3000)`

Answer (score 3):

`this` won't refer to your component class when used inside the callback function.  If the only thing being called by `setTimeout` is `this.props.getData`, then you don't need a new function to do that:

```
setTimeout(this.props.getData, 3000);
```

If you need to do additional work inside the callback function, then you can use a lambda function instead, because `this` will be the same as in the outer scope:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    // do something else
    this.props.getData();
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `this` inside your `setTimeout()` is not the `this` you are expecting it to be. Try binding the function to your current context and see if that works.

```
setTimeout(function(){
   this.props.getData();
}.bind(this), 3000);
```

Or you can use arrow functions like so:

```
setTimeout(() => this.props.getData(), 3000);
```

Arrow functions are contextless. They inherit the parent context.

References:

[Arrow functions](https://www.google.ro/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiUkvfn3vnSAhVGXBQKHdnPCWYQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FFunctions%2FArrow_functions&usg=AFQjCNGCR-aBleRFoozNm96tBHjzBNB9Aw&sig2=1mfvTF5_CIPlTfTcVwOUFg)

[Understanding JS this](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/)